# How to redirect oracle apex application with ords

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I created an oracle apex application. Now when I want to open the application I should enter the application's url, but I want to enter the IP address and browser opens my application instead of oracle apex login page. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ORDS is configured to use the APEX login page as the default page when none is specified. You can change this by modifying or adding the **misc.defaultPage** entry in your `defaults.xml` [configuration file for ORDS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/20.2/aelig/about-REST-configuration-files.html#GUID-37AA1468-DCB3-4D8B-868C-1910A0C04D68). If you set the value to **f?p=100:1**, you will be take to application 100 page 1 by default.

Comment: I edited misc.defaultPage and changed it to this: entry key="misc.defaultPage">f?p=106:9999</entry>. But nothing changed and apex login page still opens

Comment: Did you restart ORDS? If not, try restarting your Tomcat/WebLogic process to have ORDS read the changes.  It will only take effect after ORDS has been restarted.